# How to use non-static and static method together without creating an external instance in PHP

Tags: php

I have below scenario, want to use specific method as static so can i use $this for other methods or not.

```
class foobar {
    public $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        global $foo;

        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public static function foobarfunc() {
        return self::foo();
    }
    public function foo() {
        return $this->foo = 'hi';
    }
}
echo foobar::foobarfunc();
```

**ERROR:**

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

This is my scenario

```
class DB{
    public function selectQuery(){
        $data = $this->finddata();
        return "SELECT $data FROM bhumi";
    }
    public function finddata(){
        $data = ('*');
        return $data;
    }
}
class TP extends DB{
    public static $create;
    
    public function __construct(){
       $this->parentObj = new DB();
    }
    public static function printQ(){
        $d = parent::selectQuery();
        return $d;
    }
}
echo TP::printQ();
```

How to do that? this code giving me error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "_this code giving me error._" What error?

Comment: return self::foo(); <-- foo() isn't static. You need to create an instance first

Comment: what if I don't want to create an instance.

Comment: Why using static to return result of classical instance ? make no sens..

Comment: When you dont wat to create an instance, foo() should be static too. See my answer

Comment: I simply don't get what are you trying to achieve. [There is a difference between static and instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402978/php-static-vs-instance-method)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: I want to use non-static and static method together without creating an external instance.

Comment: You should create an instance inside your class. See AliShojaei's answer. But still it does not make sense to me unless you say that you want to create a static factory method as `foobarfunc`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8959150/6099347) answer. [You can also make it singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319434/singleton-pattern).

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
public static function foobarfunc() {
    $foobar = new self();
    return $foobar->foo();
}
```

Comment: is this correct way or another answer one?

Comment: @BhumiShah I think this answer makes more sense in whatever you're trying to do, since you can keep your `foo()` method non-static.

Answer (score 1):

When you dont want to create an instance, ignoring the reasons why:

```
<?php 
 class foobar {
public static $foo;

public function __construct() {
    global $foo;

    $this->foo = $foo;
}

public static function foobarfunc() {
    return self::foo();
}
public static function foo() {
    return self::$foo = 'Hi!';;
}
}
echo foobar::foobarfunc();
?>
```

Comment: is this correct way or another answer one?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function foobarfunc() {
    return self::foo();
}
```

You just want to load another static method called "foo". This method exist and is not static, so the error is valid.

You can fix it with

```
public static function foobarfunc() {
    $instance = new self();
    return $instance->foo();
}
```

Albeit, the usefullness of this use be left open.

Comment: is this correct way?

Comment: @BhumiShah There is no "correct" way. It all depends on what you need to do.