# non-static method cannot be called statically laravel

Tags: laravel-8, php-8.1

I'm trying calling the controller method directly from the blade file,
but it gives me an error like.

> Error Non-static method
> App\Http\Controllers\CallDetailsController::insertVicidialReportLog()
> cannot be called statically (View:
> /var/www/html/vicidiallaravel/resources/views/reports/call_report_export.blade.php)

below is my code.

**CallDetailsController.php**

```
public function insertVicidialReportLog($webserver_id,$authUser,$userId,$reportName,$query_date,$end_date,$shift,$file_download,$report_display_type)
    {
        //return $authUser;
        // die();
        //
        ##### BEGIN log visit to the vicidial_report_log table #####
      
        $LOGip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $LOGbrowser = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        $LOGscript_name = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
        $LOGserver_name = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
        $LOGserver_port = $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
        $LOGrequest_uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $LOGhttp_referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
        $LOGbrowser=preg_replace("/\'|\"|\\\\/","",$LOGbrowser);
        $LOGrequest_uri=preg_replace("/\'|\"|\\\\/","",$LOGrequest_uri);
        $LOGhttp_referer=preg_replace("/\'|\"|\\\\/","",$LOGhttp_referer);
        if (preg_match("/443/i",$LOGserver_port)) {$HTTPprotocol = 'https://';}
        else {$HTTPprotocol = 'http://';}
        if (($LOGserver_port == '80') or ($LOGserver_port == '443') ) {$LOGserver_port='';}
        else {$LOGserver_port = ":$LOGserver_port";}
        $LOGfull_url = "$HTTPprotocol$LOGserver_name$LOGserver_port$LOGrequest_uri";

        $LOGhostname = php_uname('n');
        if (strlen($LOGhostname)<1) {$LOGhostname='X';}
        if (strlen($LOGserver_name)<1) {$LOGserver_name='X';}
       
        $insertReportLog = DB::table('vicidial_report_log')->insertGetId([
            'event_date' => NOW(),
            'user' => $authUser,
            'ip_address' => $LOGip,
            'report_name' => $reportName,
            'browser' => $LOGbrowser,
            'referer' => $LOGhttp_referer,
            'notes' => "$LOGserver_name:$LOGserver_port $LOGscript_name |$query_date, $end_date, $shift, $file_download, $report_display_type|",
            'url' => "$LOGfull_url",
            'webserver' => "$webserver_id",
         ]);
        return $insertReportLog;  

    }
```

**call_report_export.blade.php**

```
$stmt = App\Http\Controllers\CallDetailsController::insertVicidialReportLog($webserver_id,$PHP_AUTH_USER,$PHP_AUTH_USER_ID,$report_name,$query_date,$end_date,$shift,$file_download,$report_display_type);
```

so, now how can we call that method from the Blade file?

**Laravel Framework 8.83.27**

Answer (score 1):

This is not a static method, it cannot be called statically.
Change:

```
public function insertVicidialReportLog(...)
```

To:

```
public static function insertVicidialReportLog(...)
```

Also, learn about the [differences between static and instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402978/php-static-vs-instance-method)